# Which tense to use?

Tags: tense

I was using some user name on some forum. Then I changed that name.
I want to address this in my signature.

What should I write?

- I was posting as X before.
- I used to post as X before.
- I have posted as X before.

Which one of those is the best for what I mean?

Answer (score 6):

Any of these is ok, except I would simply say "I used to post as X"; the "before" here is redundant.  However, to do what you want, I would prefer not to use any of these and use *formerly* instead:

> Bob Rodes
>   *formerly* Sasquatch

For completeness's sake, "I was posting as X before" means that over a period of time in the past, you had the ongoing habit of posting as X.  "I used to post as X" means pretty much the same thing, and I would prefer this usage.  "I have posted as X before" means that at least once in the past you posted as X.

Comment: I'd like to suggest another alternative: "Bob Rodes
(aka Sasquatch)". This is especially useful when we still occasionally use the old name. :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Or *alias* or *aliter* both meaning *otherwise*.

Comment: @StoneyB I've never heard *aliter*

Comment: I would point out that *aka* (also known as) and *alias* don't have the connotation of no longer being known as, whereas *formerly* does.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives depending on what kind of impression you want to make with your new persona.

- ex-X
- previously X
- R.I.P. X
- X has left the building
- was X
- X no more

and so on. Personally I wouldn't choose any of your three options.

Comment: Don't use 'R.I.P. X'. People will think you are a friend (or enemy, or other acquaintance) of X, and X died.

Answer (score 1):

The first one would match your situation best.

- I was posting as X before. - *I, as X, created multiple posts in the past.*
- I used to post as X before. - This is permissible but unrecommended due to ambiguity. While what you mean is *you [don't post as X] anymore*, the more intuitive interpretation is *you [don't post anymore], and while you were posting, you were posting as X*.
- I have posted as X before. - *...and there are lasting effects*, for example you know how to post there (and it's not a trivial feat); also, it allows the option that you posted there just once. Well, maybe the effects are the posts that are there or your acquaintances, but I don't think that's important to what you want to convey.